# Builtin MemCpy Chk will always overflow destination buffer

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, nsdata, memcpy

Updating my app from 32-bit to 64-bit.

According to the Apple Documentation floats are only 4 byte and I need to use CGFloat (8 byte)

I am using the `memcpy` to read in bytes. I have updated all my `sizeof(float)`s to `sizeof(CGFloat)`.

But when I do I get the Semantic issue

> *__builtin___memcpy_chk will always overflow destination buffer. Expanded from macro `memcpy`*

I updated my `NSData readDataOfLenght` to take `sizeof(CGFloat)` and it seems to work ok. Sometimes not all the data that is read in is correct.

***I am afraid I am over my head in this and could use some help.***

```
-(void) readByteData:(NSFileHandle *)fHandle Size:(NSInteger)byteSize
{
    [super readByteData:fHandle Size:byteSize];

    NSData *data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(CGFloat)];
    float r;
    memcpy(&r, [data bytes], sizeof(CGFloat));
    self.radius = r;

    int nCGPointSize = sizeof(CGFloat) * 2;
    data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:nCGPointSize];
    float xy[2];
    memcpy(xy, [data bytes], nCGPointSize);
    self.centerPos = ccp(xy[0], xy[1]);

    data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(CGFloat)];
    float start_angle;
    memcpy(&start_angle, [data bytes], sizeof(CGFloat));
    self.startAngle = start_angle;

    data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(CGFloat)];
    float end_angle;
    memcpy(&end_angle, [data bytes], sizeof(CGFloat));
    self.endAngle = end_angle;

    data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(int)];
    int d;
    memcpy(&d, [data bytes], sizeof(int));
    self.dir = d;

    flagClosed = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This instruction:

```
float r;
memcpy(&r, [data bytes], sizeof(CGFloat));
```

Tells your compiler:

> Read `sizeof(CGFloat)` (== 8 bytes!) from the location `[data bytes]`
>   and write them to `r`

**But `r` is only 4 bytes in size!** So the first 4 bytes are written to `r` and the next 4 bytes are written to whatever follows `r` in memory and this is not allowed. `memcpy` is a simple byte copy instructions, it moves any number of bytes from memory location A to memory location B, it cannot convert data types for you. If you need to convert `CGFloat` values to `float` values, then you actually need to do that conversion yourself.

```
CGFloat bigR;
memcpy(&bigR, [data bytes], sizeof(bigR));
self.radius = (float)bigR;
```

Same when reading multiple values:

```
CGFloat bigXY[2];
data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(bigXY)];
memcpy(bigXY, [data bytes], sizeof(bigXY));
self.centerPos = ccp((float)bigXY[0], (float)bixXY[1]);
```

The casts are only to make it more clear where the conversion takes place, most compilers will also compile the code without all the `(float)` casts and without complaining.

As a general rule:

```
memcpy(dst, src, size)
```

`size` **must never** be bigger than the memory `src` points to or the memory `dst` points to. In your case, `size` was always bigger than the memory `dst` pointed to.

So far the explanation why your code didn't work. However, you actually don't need to use `memcpy` at all as if you have a memory block out of multiple values of a known data type, of course you can access that memory directly without having to copy it anywhere:

```
NSData * data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(CGFloat)];
if (!data) {
    // ... handle errorr ...
}
const CGFloat * cgfloatsInData = (const CGFloat *)[data bytes];
self.radius = (float)cgfloatsInData[0];

data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(CGFloat) * 2];
if (!data) {
    // ... handle errorr ...
}
const CGFloat * cgfloatsInData = (const CGFloat *)[data bytes];
self.centerPos = ccp((float)cgfloatsInData[0], (float)cgfloatsInData[1]);
```

And so on. But this is highly inefficient, as you seem to always expect some fixed size structure with no optional values, so why not reading it as a structure? That way you only need one I/O access to read all of it and only one `NSData` object must be created by the system.

```
const struct {
    CGFloat radius;
    CGFloat xCoord;
    CGFloat yCoord;
    CGFloat startAngle;
    CGFloat endAngle;
    int dir;
} __attribute__((packed)) * entry;
// `const` as the memory `entry` will point to will be read-only.
// `* entry` means entry is a pointer to memory of a struct
// that looks as described above. __attribute__((packed)) means
// the memory must be laid out exactly as shown above and have no
// padding for better alignment of fields.

NSData * data = [fHandle readDataOfLength:sizeof(*entry)];
// `sizeof(*entry)` means the size of the memory entry points to,
// contrary to `sizeof(entry)` which would be the size of entry itself
// and that would simply be the size of a pointer on your system, 8 bytes,
// whereas `sizeof(*entry)` will be 44 bytes.

entry = (const void *)dataBytes;
// Any pointer type can be cased to `void *` and assigning
// a `void *` pointer so some pointer is always allowed by the compiler.

self.radius = (float)entry->radius;
self.centerPos = ccp((float)entry->xCoord, (float)entry->yCoord);
self.startAngle = (float)entry->startAngle;
self.endAngle = (float)entry->endAngle;
self.dir = entry->dir;
```